# Remove any rows containing values from previous row's cell's values

Tags: excel, vba, multidimensional-array, distinct, rows

I have an excel table that should contains only unique values in each row. If any of the previous cell values repeating anywhere  in the other rows, the complate row should be deleted. The example table is like so

```
Example       
Table       The result 
______      _____
0 1 3       0 1 3                   
6 4 1 5  -> 8 9 2
8 9 2
```

The second row should be cleared because the first row already contains 1 . But the third row should be there because it doesn't contains any duplicates from the previous rows.

I need excel formula to filter like so or vba code with multi dimensional array clearing the unwanted rows.

Comment: Is this table very big?

Comment: It is not big but it changes frequently

Comment: Are the number of columns and rows fixed?

Comment: Unfortunately no but they are generally limited to 5 column and 200 rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one...
It works with all the samples I took.

```
Dim i, j, k, l As Long

LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
LastCol = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column

For k = 1 To LastRow
    For i = k + 1 To LastRow
        For j = 1 To LastCol
            For l = 1 To LastCol
                If (Sheets(1).Cells(i, j).Value2 <> "") And _
                    (Sheets(1).Cells(k, j).Value2 <> "") And _
                    (Sheets(1).Cells(i, j).Value2 = Sheets(1).Cells(k, l).Value2) Then
                    Sheets(1).Cells(i, j).EntireRow.ClearContents
                End If
            Next
        Next
    Next
Next

Range("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
```